# Jackson Json Serialization : Remove Blank strings

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to exclude all Blank Strings from the resulting Json using Jackson.

I understand I can use below annotation to filter this, but this does not seem to handle Blank Strings.[Stings with just white spaces]

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `custom value filter`, Please try this and let me know if this works for you -

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.CUSTOM, valueFilter = CustomFilter.class)
```

and here is the custom filter -

```
class CustomFilter {
    public CustomFilter() {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null)
            return true;
        if(obj instanceof String){
            return ((String)obj).trim().isEmpty();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

As per the javadoc of CUSTOM filter -

```
public static final JsonInclude.Include CUSTOM
```

> Value that indicates that separate `filter` Object (specified by
>   JsonInclude.valueFilter() for value itself, and/or
>   JsonInclude.contentFilter() for contents of structured types) is to be
>   used for determining inclusion criteria. Filter object's equals()
>   method is called with value to serialize; if it returns true value is
>   excluded (that is, filtered out); if false value is included.