# Jackson serialization and remove empty space

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have some code that pulls data from a DB and populates a POJO.  That POJO then gets serialized and pushed into an elasticsearch cluster.

The problem I am having is that one of the fields in the database was free text and people just put in a  to get around the required field.

I'd like to be able to strip that whitespace out when pushing to elastic.

Here's an example of my pojo

```
public class Destination {
    Long id;
    ...
    ...
    String Address;

}
```

I am using Jackson to turn this into JSON using the ObjectMapper class. ie
`mapper.convertTo(dest, Map.class)`

When I view the value in elastic I am seeing:

`{"id":1, ..., "address": " "}`

Ideally, in this case, I'd **just** like to see the "id" property since the "address" is essentially null.

I've tried using ObjectMapper's serialization properties, but nothing seems to be working.  Is there a standard way that this is being handled?  How does Spring handle this?

I've seen similar questions asked ([Jackson Json Serialization : Remove Blank strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821176/jackson-json-serialization-remove-blank-strings)), but I'm not sure how to apply that solution globally, rather than just at the class level, or if you can apply it globally.

Comment: Well, you could try to override the standard string serializer, e.g. via `objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(String.class, new YourCustomStringSerializer()));`. Just make sure to apply that to the correct objectmapper instance.

Comment: Isn't it marked final?

Comment: The standard string deserializer? It might be (didn't use it directly myself) but writing a completely new one shouldn't be too hard - you'd just need to extend `JsonSerializer<String>` and implement a single method: `serialize(...)`.

Comment: I believe this is the class you're referring to correct?  https://github.com/netwelfare/jsonstar/blob/master/code/jackson-databind-jackson-databind-2.0.0-RC1/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StringSerializer.java

Comment: Yes, seems to be the one. As you can see, it isn't that complex and copying it to provide your own shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Your comment above worked perfectly and solved my issue.

Comment: make it an answer?